# PHPUnit laravel in a form with multiple uploaded file

Tags: laravel, file, testing, phpunit

---

I've a problem, I'm trying test my aplicattion with PHPUnit, in that aplicattion I've multiple forms where the user can upload files, and since Admin can upload differents files, I'm trying test a form where the admin can upload an image, and an audio, but I don't get it; here's my code:

> 

```
public function testCreateAudiobooks()
    {

        Storage::fake('uploads/audiobooks/cover_pages');
        Session::start();

        $response = $this->json('POST', 'admin-audiobooks', [
            'audiobook_title'       => 'Audiolibro con Unit',
            'audiobook_description' => 'Descripción de audiolibro desde Unit',
            'audiobook_author'      => 'PHPUnit',
            'audiobook_section'     => 'Pruebas',
            'audiobook_keywords'    => 'Unit',
            'audiobook_storyteller' => 'Luis',
            'audiobook_duration'    => '15',
            'audiobook_visibility'  => 'Visible',
            'audiobook_cover_page'  => UploadedFile::fake()->image('45.png'),
            'audiobook_location'    => UploadedFile::fake(),
            '_token' => csrf_token()
        ]);

        Storage::disk('uploads/audiobooks/cover_pages')->assertMissing('45.png');

        $response->assertRedirect();
    }
```

As you can see, I pass the UploadedFile in audiobook_cover_page, but I dunno how can pass something similar for the audiobook_location

I found this [artcile](https://laravel-news.com/testing-file-uploads-with-laravel), and I try do something similar, but still didn't

If someone can help me, I'll be really gratefull!

Comment: That depends on what you want inside audiobook_location. Is it a string like the others? Otherwise you can just use `UploadedFile::fake()->create('something.txt', 128);` and create any file you like apparently.

Comment: I'll try with that one, thanks man